# Wrapping existing JS code as Angularjs Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have a JS library with some functions like this:

```
function TestService() {
}

TestService.init = function() {
 ------
}

TestService.foo = function() {
--------------
}
```

Now this is an old library and would like to use these functions in angular code. Is there a way we can wrap it up as service/factory and use it properly?
Appreciate help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class is designed to be instantiated with `new`, just pass it to `.service`:

```
app.service('testService', TestService);
```

Angular will call `new` on it once to create a singleton.

**Edit:**

I thought your question had an error and the functions were really supposed to be assigned to the prototype.

If you just need that function, return it using a factory or constant:

```
app.factory('testService', function() {
    return TestService:
});
```

Or:

```
app.constant('testService', TestService);
```

Comment: didn't know angular was doing it by himself, that's pretty sweet

Comment: Yep, that's main difference between `.factory` and `.service`. When you use `.factory` you have to pass it a function that returns an object. When you use `.service` you pass it a constructor function on which it will call `new`.

Comment: I am using ES 6 syntax which requires class structure.

Comment: @FrankModica Didn't work for me. My function structure is as mentioned above.

Comment: It should still work. Classes are just syntax sugar.

Comment: Oh I assumed you made a mistake in your question and the functions were actually being attached to the prototype.

Comment: No there is no  prototype it is just a js file with set of functions.

Comment: So then you don't need it to be called with `new`?

Comment: If you just need to use that function, then use `.factory` or `.constant`. See my update.

Comment: Awsome thanks, it worked !  Learnt something new today.

Comment: You're welcome. Which did you end up using? You might want to read up all of the different injectable types (provider, service, factory, constant, value).

Comment: I used this one:.factory('TestService', () => {
  return TestService;
});

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course :

```
// trying to gimmick your library
function test() {}

test.prototype.hey = function() {
    alert('hey');
}

test.prototype.hoy = function() {
    alert('hoy');
}

app.factory('testFactory', function() {
    // that's where your using your library
    return new test();           
});
```

And then use it in controller :

```
// controller function
function HelloCtrl($scope, testFactory) {
    testFactory.hey();
}
```

try it :

http://jsfiddle.net/ufLf50n1/

Comment: So i have to use prototype inheritance. Can't i use it as it is and then wrap it as service and use in controllers via injection. This lib changes from time to time and we are use it through cdn.

Comment: prototype was just an exemple of possible librabry

Answer (score 0):

You can use returning `class` from `angular.factory`:

```js
class TestService {
  constructor() {
    console.log('instance initialized');
  }

  static init() {
    console.log('static init')
  }

  static foo() {
    console.log('static foo');
  }
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('TestService', () => TestService)
  .run((TestService) => {
    new TestService();
    TestService.init();
    TestService.foo();
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app"></div>
```

Comment: How does rewriting as a `class` help? It does not appear as though the AngularJS syntax would differ between the two...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan not rewriting but returning. The class part itself is not that important, it's just more convenient to write in es6 style (the question tag indicates ecmascript6). What is important though is returning the library api, without calling new or whatever in service.  Letting the judgement over the service usage to be commited in the controller by passing it integrally through into controller with all static props.